# Avoiding RyanAir's rip-offs in a really cheap ticket

Tags: budget, low-cost-carriers, tourist-traps

I got a pair of really cheap return tickets from Ryanair. I have never taken flights for so little money. It was so cheap that it makes me nervous, Ryanair being what it is.

So, we are not checking-in any luggage (just a laptop bag each as carry-on). We are not reserving any seats and have paid with a Visa card. They have already charged it. It was the same price as the offer. We'll check-in online 3-4 days before the flight, print the boarding passes and take our passports. We'll arrive 1.5-2 hours in advance. We won't be taking any overpriced snacks on board. I assume the bathroom on board is still for free, but if it's not, we can pee before the flight.

Is there any pitfall here, any possibility of being ripped-off by them?

Comment: How large are your bags?  According to https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-1, if you don't pay any fees, you can only carry on a "small bag" of up to 35x20x20 cm.  Many laptops are bigger than that.  If yours is, then it appears that your bag will be put in the hold.  It's free, but are you okay with your laptop going in the hold?

Comment: @NateEldredge a laptop bag doesn't necessarily contain a laptop, especially in this context.

Comment: @NateEldredge: now that I see, 35x20x20cm for a laptop bag are really strange parameters. The 35cm length is OK, but 20cm width is too little. No laptop bag could be that narrow. And 20cm height, is too much.

Comment: Now, maybe someone who has actually flown Ryanair can tell us whether this is really enforced.

Comment: Note that you are also free to bring your own snacks on board (drinks are more complicated: You could try to find a water fountain at the airport but buying anything landside is often more expensive than on the plane).

Comment: If you need more baggage Ryanair allows you to place one bag upto 55 x 40 x 20cm & 10kg in the hold free of charge, however, this will be taken from you at the gate,  you do not necessarily need to go to the gate to use this and it's in addition to the aforementioned requirements. And will have to be all associated requirements with taking a bag through security. https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-1

Comment: @Relaxed: at most airports can bring an empty water bottle through security and fill it air-side. Many airports actually have dedicated water bottle fill stations for that

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, I know, I just mentioned that. Also, I have seen airport without water fountains.

Comment: If you are asked to put your carry on bag in the hold because of lack of cabin space, you’ll need to remember to remove any valuables https://press.which.co.uk/whichpressreleases/be-prepared-if-parted-with-your-bag-on-short-haul-flights/

Answer (score 7):

2 things that tripped us up:  if you check in at the counter instead of online there’s a hefty extra fee, and a purse counts as one piece of luggage, so you’ll have to stuff it into your carry-on or pay extra.